# Cannot Launch to gnome GUI on Kali Sana after dist-upgrade

Tags: xorg, kali-linux, gui, segmentation-fault, startx

I'm facing some problems on Kali Sana 2.0, I dist-upgrade my system to Kali Sana days ago, and as usual all I had to type to start the GUI is:

`# startx`

But 'startx' returns 'segmentation fault' errors, and what I did after was to search for the Xorg.conf file, but the file was missing. So I tried:

`# Xorg -configure`

But without any luck, it gives the same segmentation fault errors. The /var/log/Xorg.0.log file reports exactly the same errors that is displayed by '# startx or # Xorg -configure'.

This is the output (error report) of Xorg.0.log file:

`root@GuardianAngel:~# cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log 
[   353.357] 
X.Org X Server 1.17.2
Release Date: 2015-06-16
[   353.358] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   353.358] Build Operating System: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[   353.358] Current Operating System: Linux GuardianAngel 4.0.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.0.4-1+kali2 (2015-06-03) x86_64
[   353.358] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.0.0-kali1-amd64 root=UUID=d56a0934-d8e9-4c6f-97a3-0f3f2585f3fb ro initrd=/install/gtk/initrd.gz quiet
[   353.358] Build Date: 01 July 2015  05:17:14PM
[   353.358] xorg-server 2:1.17.2-1 (http://www.debian.org/support) 
[   353.358] Current version of pixman: 0.32.6
[   353.358]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   353.358] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   353.358] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Aug 19 09:11:15 2015
[   353.401] (II) Loader magic: 0x7f549f347d80
[   353.401] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   353.402]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   353.402]    X.Org Video Driver: 19.0
[   353.402]    X.Org XInput driver : 21.0
[   353.402]    X.Org Server Extension : 9.0[   353.402] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[   353.404] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0046:104d:9069 rev 2, Mem @ 0xd0000000/4194304, 0xc0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00007050/8
[   353.404] (EE) 
[   353.404] (EE) Backtrace:
[   353.404] (EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x56) [0x7f549f0c0df6]
[   353.405] (EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (0x7f549ef0e000+0x1b7009) [0x7f549f0c5009]
[   353.405] (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7f549cc02000+0x35180) [0x7f549cc37180]
[   353.405] (EE) 3: /usr/bin/X (xf86PlatformMatchDriver+0xa1) [0x7f549efc7211]
[   353.405] (EE) 4: /usr/bin/X (0x7f549ef0e000+0xbbf4d) [0x7f549efc9f4d]
[   353.405] (EE) 5: /usr/bin/X (0x7f549ef0e000+0xbc0ec) [0x7f549efca0ec]
[   353.405] (EE) 6: /usr/bin/X (InitOutput+0x70f) [0x7f549efa8a9f]
[   353.405] (EE) 7: /usr/bin/X (0x7f549ef0e000+0x5c0aa) [0x7f549ef6a0aa]
[   353.405] (EE) 8: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f549cc23b45]
[   353.405] (EE) 9: /usr/bin/X (0x7f549ef0e000+0x4668e) [0x7f549ef5468e]
[   353.405] (EE) 
[   353.406] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x50
[   353.408] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[   353.410] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[   353.411] (EE) 
[   353.412] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[   353.416] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[   353.417] (EE)`

Please help. If you need additional info please ask me.

Comment: Try `gnome-session --session=gnome-shell` instead.

Comment: @McSinyx I tried that, it hangs.